# Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerException (0x80004005): The prefix 'https://+:44384/' is already registered

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I was able to run my asp.net core web app on my local service fabric cluster successfully for some time at https://localhost:44384.
But now I started seeing error message "'https://+:44384/' is already registered" and my application won't start the browser window.
On my local machine I am not using this port 44384 for any other apps. So why I am getting the above error message? Even if I change port to some other number, I am still getting the same error message mentioning the smae port error message "'https://+:44384/' is already registered" .

Any suggestiongs to resolve this error ?

Error message :

> Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener: Information: Listening on
>   prefix: https://+:44384/ Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener: Error:
>   Start
>
> Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerException (0x80004005): The
>   prefix 'https://+:44384/' is already registered.    at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String uriPrefix,
>   Int32 contextId)    at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup
>   urlGroup)    at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener.Start()
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener: Error: Start
>
> Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerException (0x80004005): The
>   prefix 'https://+:44384/' is already registered.    at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String uriPrefix,
>   Int32 contextId)    at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup
>   urlGroup)    at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener.Start()
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener: Error: Start
>
> Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerException (0x80004005): The
>   prefix 'https://+:44384/' is already registered.    at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String uriPrefix,
>   Int32 contextId)    at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup
>   urlGroup)    at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener.Start()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're running a five node development cluster. (Perhaps this was a 1 node cluster before?). If you are, you'll run into trouble when deploying services to those nodes, as they all use the same network stack.
Solution:

Deploy 1 instance of your web app - service locally

> when you run a web service locally, you need to ensure that only one
>   instance of the service is running. Otherwise, you run into conflicts
>   from multiple processes that are listening on the same path and port.
>   As a result, the web service instance count should be set to "1" for
>   local deployments.

[more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore)

[and here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see the PID of anything using that port with:

`netstat -a -n -o`